# Simply Connected Spaces

Tags: general-topology

Informally, an object in our space is [simply connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_space) if it consists of one piece and does not have any "holes" that pass all the way through it. For example, neither a doughnut nor a coffee cup (with handle) is simply connected, but a hollow rubber ball is simply connected.

In two dimensions, a circle is not simply connected, but a disk and a line are (not sure how a line is, but ok). Spaces that are connected but not simply connected are called non-simply connected or multiply connected.

Is the sphere the only 3d object that can be a truly connected space?

Or is this more aptly used in 1D spaces?

Comment: What do you mean by "truly connected"? Do you mean "connected and simply connected"?

Comment: yes - sorry simply connected

Comment: Well, a disc can lie in three-dimensional space, and it is just as simply connected there.

Comment: but only on 1 dimension.  If the connection goes around the flat side of the disc, it is not simply connected anymore.  This would be like a torus, wouldn't it?

Comment: $R^n$ minus a finite amount of points is simply connected for $n \geq 3$. So you could take any open ball in $R^3$ minus a finite amount of points, and that will be simply connected. They are not homeomorphic to a sphere.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{R}^3$ is simply connected, and not homeomorphic to the sphere.